# How Can I Get the Arguments of Function Calls from the Firebug Profiler?

Tags: javascript, firebug, arguments, profiler, function-calls

Firebug profiler outputs the functions called, but not the arguments/parameters of each function call. Is there any way to get those arguments?

I've dug through the DOM tab for any of the given function calls that I know would have to have had some arguments, but was unsuccessful in pulling out any details.

Edit: Still looking for a solution to this. I'd add a bounty if I had 50 points, but at the moment it's at 49! I can't mark this as solved though, because none of the two provided answers are really definitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look and couldn't see the functionality, also firebug displays a count of the number of times a function is called in the profiler and doesn't seem to actually log individual calls in the UI, although I may be wrong.

Obvious question, depending what you actually trying to achieve would it not by better to simply log out the args if you need to know what they are?

Comment: I'm dealing with someone else's scripts. Trying to use Firebug to help me make a bookmarklet, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Can't the arguments be different every time it's called?

If you're actually looking for performance problems, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

If you want to know the function arguments, it will also give you that.